# Drag and Drop Image in GardenProject

Tags: java, image, drag-and-drop

I need to do in college program design gardens.
I searched a lot about dragging a picture but nothing directly, affect my problem.
I need help in this case. Program is run via drag-drop but do not know how to do this. Please help

**I found a few examples BUT they are constants path to picture, there is no drag from Composite to a some panel and dragged picture don't stay on start position**

[image: this]
 is my program :

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MenuItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ExpandBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ExpandItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MessageBox;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scale;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TrayItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ControlEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ControlListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;

import java.awt.Frame;

import org.eclipse.swt.awt.SWT_AWT;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle.Control;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.TransferHandler;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;


public class ogrod {


    protected Shell shlProjectgarden;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ogrod window = new ogrod();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shlProjectgarden.open();
        shlProjectgarden.layout();
        while (!shlProjectgarden.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */
    protected void createContents() {
        shlProjectgarden = new Shell();
        shlProjectgarden.setSize(794, 515);
        shlProjectgarden.setText("projectGARDEN");
        shlProjectgarden.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, false));

        Menu menu = new Menu(shlProjectgarden, SWT.BAR);
        shlProjectgarden.setMenuBar(menu);

        MenuItem mntmPlik = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.NONE);
        mntmPlik.setText("File");

        MenuItem mntmEdycja = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.NONE);
        mntmEdycja.setText("Edit");

        MenuItem mntmNarzedzia = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.NONE);
        mntmNarzedzia.setText("Tools");

        MenuItem mntmWidok = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.NONE);
        mntmWidok.setText("View");

        MenuItem mntmPomoc = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.NONE);
        mntmPomoc.setText("Help");

        Button btnOtwrz = new Button(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);
        btnOtwrz.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("D:\\PROJEKT PROGRAMOWANIE\\icons\\Open-icon.png"));
        btnOtwrz.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1));
        btnOtwrz.setText("Open");

        Button btnZapisz = new Button(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);
        btnZapisz.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1));
        btnZapisz.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("D:\\PROJEKT PROGRAMOWANIE\\icons\\Save-icon.png"));
        btnZapisz.setText("Save");

        Button btnCofnij = new Button(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);
        btnCofnij.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1));
        btnCofnij.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("D:\\PROJEKT PROGRAMOWANIE\\icons\\Undo-icon.png"));
        btnCofnij.setText("Undo");

        Button btnUsu = new Button(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);
        btnUsu.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("D:\\PROJEKT PROGRAMOWANIE\\icons\\delete-icon.png"));
        btnUsu.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1));
        btnUsu.setText("Delete");

        Button btnObr = new Button(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);
        btnObr.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1));
        btnObr.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("D:\\PROJEKT PROGRAMOWANIE\\icons\\rotate1.png"));
        btnObr.setText("Turn");

        Button button = new Button(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);
        button.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1));
        button.setText("Turn");
        button.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("D:\\PROJEKT PROGRAMOWANIE\\icons\\rotate2.png"));

        Button btnKolor = new Button(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);
        btnKolor.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1));
        btnKolor.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("D:\\PROJEKT PROGRAMOWANIE\\icons\\gradient.png"));
        btnKolor.setText("Color");

        Button btnWyjd = new Button(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);
        btnWyjd.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("D:\\PROJEKT PROGRAMOWANIE\\icons\\exit.png"));
        btnWyjd.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1));
        btnWyjd.setText("Exit");
        new Label(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);

        //First EXPAND BAR
        ExpandBar expandBar = new ExpandBar(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);
        GridData gd_expandBar = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, false, true, 2, 1);
        gd_expandBar.widthHint = 178;
        expandBar.setLayoutData(gd_expandBar);


        // item Rosliny
        Composite compositePlants = new Composite(expandBar, SWT.NONE);
        RowLayout layout = new RowLayout();
        compositePlants.setLayout(layout);

            Label ros1 = new Label(compositePlants,SWT.PUSH);
            ros1.setAlignment(SWT.CENTER);
            ros1.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("D:\\Krzysiek\\workspace\\GardenProject\\drzewo.png"));

        ExpandItem item0 = new ExpandItem(expandBar, SWT.NONE, 0);
        item0.setText("Plants");
        item0.setHeight(compositePlants.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).y);
        item0.setControl(compositePlants);

        Label label = new Label(compositePlants, SWT.NONE);
        label.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("D:\\Krzysiek\\workspace\\GardenProject\\flowers1.png"));

        Label label_5 = new Label(compositePlants, SWT.NONE);
        label_5.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("D:\\Krzysiek\\workspace\\GardenProject\\flowers3.png"));

        item0.setExpanded(true);

        ExpandItem furnitures = new ExpandItem(expandBar, SWT.NONE);
        furnitures.setExpanded(true);
        furnitures.setText("Garden Furniture");


        ExpandBar expandBar_5 = new ExpandBar(expandBar, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        furnitures.setControl(expandBar_5);

        Composite composite = new Composite(expandBar, SWT.NONE);
        furnitures.setControl(composite);
        composite.setLayout(new RowLayout());

        Label label_1 = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
        label_1.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("D:\\Krzysiek\\workspace\\GardenProject\\stol1.png"));
        label_1.setAlignment(SWT.CENTER);

        Label label_2 = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
        label_2.setAlignment(SWT.CENTER);
        label_2.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("D:\\Krzysiek\\workspace\\GardenProject\\lawka1.png"));
        furnitures.setHeight(furnitures.getControl().computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).y);


        ExpandItem paths = new ExpandItem(expandBar, SWT.NONE);
        paths.setExpanded(true);
        paths.setText("Paths");

        ExpandBar expandBar_6 = new ExpandBar(expandBar, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        paths.setControl(expandBar_6);

        Composite composite_1 = new Composite(expandBar, SWT.NONE);
        paths.setControl(composite_1);
        composite_1.setLayout(new RowLayout());

        Label label_3 = new Label(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
        label_3.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("D:\\Krzysiek\\workspace\\GardenProject\\sciezka2.png"));
        label_3.setAlignment(SWT.CENTER);
        paths.setHeight(paths.getControl().computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).y);



        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);
        canvas.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GREEN));
        GridData gd_canvas = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, true, 6, 1);
        gd_canvas.heightHint = 227;
        canvas.setLayoutData(gd_canvas);
        new Label(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);

        Scale scale = new Scale(shlProjectgarden, SWT.NONE);
        GridData gd_scale = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BOTTOM, false, false, 6, 1);
        gd_scale.heightHint = 36;
        scale.setLayoutData(gd_scale);

    }
}
```

Comment: *"this is my program :"*  What on Earth made you think we'd need to see a screen-shot of your app.?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Sooner, pop-corn app doesn't have a code?

Comment: So you expect us to read all of that and debug it? o.O

Comment: i want know how can i drag and drop my pictures on canvas panel